# How to perform Computations in Array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two array lists.
One Array list named **FinalAmount**.

Which contains Columns like: Name,AccountNo,AccntType,Amount,FinalDate

```
Example: Peter,10025,Savings,50000,20150408

         Stuart,10054,Savings,21000,20150608
```

Second Array list named **Transactions**.

Which contains Columns like:Name,AccntNo,transactedAmount,Date

```
Example: Peter,10025,5000,20150404

         Stuart,10054,1000,20150406
```

I want to subtract the transactedAmount(Transactions Array list) which fall under Final Date from the Amount(FinalAmount Array list). and remove that Row after subtraction from the Transactions Array list.

So the Output of **FinalAmount** array list be

```
Sample Output: Peter,10025,Savings,45000,20150408

               Stuart,10054,Savings,20000,20150608
```

And Both the rows from **Transactions** array list will be removed.

Please share your thoughts or code if you have an approach in mind.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

and 

http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-list-collection-tutorial-and-examples

check both and tell if you really want to do it??

Comment: @holidayCoder Thanks for the links & yes I REALLY want to do it.

Comment: because your `list` contains both `integer and string` and therefore it is complex but you can try map instead *if you want only these 3 values to evulate*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample answer .When I checked your question,I saw that I need to create one person class with name,accountNo,amount,accType,Date.When we check two array List to subtract,we need to find same AccountNo in both array.So we need to use contains method and I override equal and hashCode.My Sample Person class is just like:
package java7.demo;

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int accountNo;
    private String accType;
    private int amount;
    private Date date;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAccountNo() {
        return accountNo;
    }
    public void setAccountNo(int accountNo) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }
    public String getAccType() {
        return accType;
    }
    public void setAccType(String accType) {
        this.accType = accType;
    }
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + accountNo;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (accountNo != other.accountNo)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name=" + name + ", accountNo=" + accountNo
                + ", accType=" + accType + ", amount=" + amount + ", date="
                + date + "";
    }




}
```

Main Class is just like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class AccountSubtractionTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<Person>FinalAmount = new ArrayList<Person>();
        List<Person>Transcation = new ArrayList<Person>();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Date d1 = new Date("01/01/2016");
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Date d2 = new Date("04/01/2016");
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setName("Peter");
        p1.setAccountNo(1234);
        p1.setAccType("Saving");
        p1.setAmount(5000);
        p1.setDate(d1);


        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setName("Robin");
        p2.setAccountNo(2222);
        p2.setAccType("Saving");
        p2.setAmount(5000);
        p2.setDate(new Date("02/02/2016"));

        FinalAmount.add(p1);
        FinalAmount.add(p2);

        Person p3 = new Person();
        p3.setName("Peter");
        p3.setAccountNo(1234);
        p3.setAccType("Saving");
        p3.setAmount(1000);
        p3.setDate(d2);

        Person p4 = new Person();
        p4.setName("Robin");
        p4.setAccountNo(2222);
        p4.setAccType("Saving");
        p4.setAmount(2000);
        p4.setDate(new Date("04/02/2016"));

        Transcation.add(p3);
        Transcation.add(p4);

        for(Person p:FinalAmount){
            if(Transcation.contains(p)){
                int index = Transcation.indexOf(p);
                Person person = Transcation.get(index);
                int amount = p.getAmount() - person.getAmount();
                p.setAmount(amount);
                Transcation.remove(index);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<FinalAmount.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(FinalAmount.get(i));
        }






    }

}
```

in main class,i just use Date d1 = new Date("01/01/2016").So you need to change the date type format that you want to use.My date is just for sample.When I run the code output get is just like:

```
name=Peter, accountNo=1234, accType=Saving, amount=4000, date=Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 MMT 2016
name=Robin, accountNo=2222, accType=Saving, amount=3000, date=Tue Feb 02 00:00:00 MMT 2016
```

Please run the two classes that I gave as sample and Please see which code you need to modify.